# reachability returns host reachable even when a host name is non-existant

Tags: iphone, reachability

Many questions about reachability, but no one seem to have the problem I do...
As many examples show I use reachability in this way:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];

hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.google.com"] retain];
[hostReach startNotifier];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: hostReach];
```

And this works just fine. However, if I change the host name to a nonexistent one, e.g., www.nonexistanthostforsure.com, reachability still has the host reachable. Now, reading the apple document, I was under impression that the reachability can not tell me if the host (server) is online. In this case, the result would make sense, but then the question is why bother with the host name at all?

Answer (score 0):

"*Why bother with the host name at all?*"

I agree.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];

hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
[hostReach startNotifier];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: hostReach];
```

The [Apple Reachability docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_5) state:

> reachabilityForInternetConnection- checks whether the default route is available.
>   Should be used by applications that do not connect to a particular host

If you check whether the default route is available, and then poll your server and the connection times out, you can still take actions like displaying a "Unable to connect to server" message without having to test Reachability against a particular hostname. It essentially accomplishes the same thing, except it's more natural since the error handling code is in the middle of your polling code, so you don't have to call to a global Reachability handler for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I seem not to be able to find something reliable to check if server is online. I tried:
NSURLResponse *response=nil;NSError *error=nil;
    NSData *data = nil;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nonexistantserver.com/"]];

    data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

But even this returns no error and data and response returned are not nil!

There must be something reliable out there to check if server is on.

Comment: There's a more reliable version of the Reachability code [here](http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24)

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help me. However, I still have the same problem. Even your suggested version of reachability doesn't answer my needs - to be able to tell if my server is up! And the code I posted in my previous comment also doesn't help (NSURLConnection) as it never fails even when I use non existent server.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening a TCP/IP plain socket to port 21 on that server? If it succeeds, you will know host is online....

Answer (score 0):

Reachability only checks if your host url request can escape out of your device to your router, it does not confirm if your request reaches the actual server

I think the best way to check the availability of host address is by checking the results of NSURL Request.

```
NSString *url= @"http://google.com";
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqURL]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Using this bit of Code, if your device cannot reach the provided URL, it provides some output to the error variable, if it can access the URL Request, error is Nil.

Reachability gives a positive output even if you URL packets can route out from your device and never reach the host server.